# Rearrange object DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to rearrange an object dataframe to be in DDMMYYYY format.
The original format was MM/DD/YYYY.

```
import string
import pandas as pd
csv_file = 'export.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, index_col=False)

df["Date1"] = df["Order_Date"].str.split(" ").str.get(0)
df["Date"] = df["Date1"].str.split("/")
zz= df["Date"]
print(zz)


>>>

0       [11, 01, 2022]
1       [11, 01, 2022]
2       [11, 01, 2022]
3       [11, 01, 2022]
4       [11, 01, 2022]
             ...      
2768    [11, 22, 2022]
2769    [11, 22, 2022]
2770    [11, 22, 2022]
2771    [11, 22, 2022]
2772    [11, 22, 2022]
Name: Date, Length: 2773, dtype: object
```

I want the output to be like this

```
>>>

0       [01112022]
1       [01112022]
2       [01112022]
3       [01112022]
4       [01112022]
             ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead solitting convert column to datetimes by[`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Order_Date"].str.split().str.get(0)).dt.strftime('%d%m%Y')
```

Or use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for valeus before first space:

```
df["Date"] = (pd.to_datetime(df["Order_Date"].str.extract('(.*)\s+', expand=False))
                .dt.strftime('%d%m%Y'))
```